# How to rename Profile link in wp-admin page

Tags: admin-menu

i want to modify the profile link in wp-admin to **Settings**

I want to rename the 3 below things to Settings which are marked in red

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the menu title is easy enough, you just need to place this in your **functions.php** file -

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_change_admin_menu');
function my_change_admin_menu(){

    global $menu;
    $menu[70][0] = 'New profile menu title';

}
```

However, you cannot change the title of this page via WordPress, not the update button text, but if you **really** need to do so you can use some jQuery -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#profile-page > h2').text('New profile menu title');
    $('#profile-page input#submit').attr('value', 'New updatew button text');

});
```

Comment: please check this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/178675/67596

Comment: Please help me with this too ....http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178678/how-to-remove-comments-option-from-wp-admin-bar-and-modify-profile-icon

Comment: Please don't spam the comments with links to other questions of yours. I and others review new/unanswered questions and will help where we can.  Please note also that while I understand you are new, I'm not always willing to help when you don't appear to be helping yourself - please post your research and code examples (where applicable) in your question. For your reference - [How do I ask a good question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).